# Set caret at beginning of contenteditable div whose first child is a span, not working properly on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, range

I have a contenteditable div whose first child is a span

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 400px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black" id="editable"><span
            style="color: blueviolet; font-size: large; padding: 5px;">mention</span> text text text<br><br>123
    <b>123</b>text text text
</div>
```

I then set caret to beginning of div

```
function setCaret() {
    var el = document.getElementById("editable");
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(el, 0);
    range.setEnd(el.childNodes[0], 0);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    el.focus();
}
```

Then I type a character. My expectation is that character belongs to an independent text node. That's true for firefox but not for chrome. Please give me advices.

Firefox:
[example on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtQFO.png)

Chrome:
[example on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW3VS.png)

Demo at this: https://jsfiddle.net/khiemnguyen/kx61bd0q/

This error also occurs when entering a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat a little and inject a single space before the `span` and use that as the `childNodes[0]` reference. The `setStartBefore` and `setEndBefore` offer no difference to the approach you have used but with the new space the caret is outwith the span.

```js
function setCaret() {
    var el = document.getElementById("editable");
        el.insertBefore( document.createTextNode( '\u00A0' ),el.firstElementChild );
        el.focus();
        
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();

    range.setStartBefore( el.firstElementChild );
    range.setEndBefore( el.firstElementChild );
    
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range); 
}

setCaret();
```

```css
#banana{color:blue;margin:0.25rem;padding:0.25rem;border:1px solid blue}
#editable{width: 400px; height: 100px; margin:5rem; padding:1rem; border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="editable">
  <span id='banana'>mention</span>
  text text text<br><br>123
  <b>123</b>text text text
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I already know that solution, but then can I delete that text node, then. This error also occurs when entering a new line.